# Please Help Python Looping

Tags: python, loops

I’m trying to find out how to do this/ get around it

```py
count = 0
def main():
    def test():
        if count == 0:
            print('it worked')
            count = count + 1
        elif count == 1:
            print('it worked2')
            count = count + 1
        if count == 2:
            print('It all worked YAY!')
    test()
    test()
main()
```

I’m trying define count at the start and then inside the function i want to have it run once and than that sets count to 1, once it runs again it sets it equal to 2 and than it runs through the last if because count would equal 2 however im getting local variable 'count' referenced before assignment i tried defining it inside the function but than on the seccond run through count would be reset back to 0 if anyone has any way of helping that would be amazing!!

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to access a global variable inside a function and modify it, you must declare that with the `global` keyword:

```
count = 0
def main():
    def test():
        global count
        if count == 0:
            print('it worked')
            count = count + 1
        elif count == 1:
            print('it worked2')
            count = count + 1
        if count == 2:
            print('It all worked YAY!')
    test()
    test()
main()
```

Without the global keyword, you're *shadowing* the global variable with a local variable named count.  And since you didn't initialize that shadow variable, you get this error.

Comment: Thank you so much man